# Is there a simple Java Regex (*SKIP)(*F) alternative?

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I am making a program in Java, and have run into a slight problem using Regular Expressions. I want to capture everything not enclosed in quotes. I have a regex pattern for that, [right here](https://regex101.com/r/eQ4xS1/1), but the issue is, it cannot be used in Java. It uses the `(*SKIP)(*F)` trick to skip over the `".*"`, and find anything else(using `[^\W]`), but as I said, it cannot be used in Java. I have another pattern that is close, but not quite what I need, [right here](https://regex101.com/r/eJ5cR7/2). It will find everything that does not have quotes directly in front or behind it. The issue with that one, is that If I have something like this: `Test1 "Hello World!" Test2`, and will grab `Test1`, `Test2`, AND `World`. I do not want to get `World`, because it is in the quotes. What I want to know, is if it is even possible to do what I want, and how if so.

Comment: If you are sure about quotes, this single regex `[^"]++((?="(?<=\b))|\s*$)` does it. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rX4aY1/1)

Comment: @revo The thing is, it grabs the spaces. Is there a way to not get the spaces, like using `[^\W]` (I cannot figure it out :P )

Comment: I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These verbs are a quite useful way to tell the regex engine (PCRE in this case) that you want to discard those matches.

Java doesn't have these verbs but you can use the same approach on java without the verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)`, and then capture the content you want... so you can use:

```
".*"|([^\W]+)
or
".*"|(\w+)
```

And then grab the content from the capturing group 1.

```
String text = "test1 \"hello world!\" test2";

Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\".*\"|([^\\W]+)");
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("Text: "+m.group(1));
    }
}
```

**[IDEOne Demo](https://ideone.com/kX9Rd2)**

This is well known as the *discard technique*, where you can discard all the patterns that aren't captured and focus on the one you want to capture, for instance, if you have:

```
".*"|'.*'|`.*`|([^\W]+)
```

This will match all the patterns but will conly capture the last one

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Well, the way that I am doing it, is something like this: https://ideone.com/4BdyeB and based on the output, it is not working. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @mttprvst13 you must grab the content from capturing group using `m.group(1)` that's the trick. In my answer you can find the IDEOne demo to see it working

Answer (score 2):

You must match the content you want to avoid and use a capture group to extract what you want *(I don't think there is an other way)*. A convenient pattern to do that can be:

```
(?:[^\w"]+|"[^"]*")*+(\w+)
```

that returns a result in the capture group 1 for each match. [demo](http://fiddle.re/dzecja)

Note: if you want to use the pattern for a replacement, put the first part in a capture group too and start the replacement string with a reference to this group:

```
((?:[^\w"]+|"[^"]*")*+)(\w+)
```

Other way, split your string with: `(?:[^\w"]+|"[^"]*")+`

You can change `"[^"]*"` to `"[^"\\]*+(?s:\\.[^"\\]*)*+"?` to handle escaped quotes inside quoted parts and an eventual missing closing quote.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I can't yet comment on other posts, but Federico Piazza's solution will fail if there are multiple sets of quotes.  For example if your text was the following:

```
String text = "test1 \"hello world!\" test2 \"foobar\" test3";
```

In this case it would print

```
test1
test3
```

and completely skip test2

Instead use the pattern

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"|([\\w]+)");
```

The `?` will cause the `.*` operator to be non-greedy and find the next quote rather than the last quote.  So to essentially copy his answer you could do the following.

```
String text = "test1 \"hello world!\" test2 \"foobar\" test3";

Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\".*?\"|([\\w]+)");
Matcher m = ptrn.matcher(text);

while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("Text: "+m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch on the greedy vs non-greedy edit.  That was an unfortunate typo that completely changed the meaning on me.

Answer (score 0):

You want words outside of quotes with excluding trailing spaces:

```
[^"\s]++((?=\s*"[^\s])|(?=\s*$)|(?=[^"]+\s+"))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rX4aY1/3)

It fails if:

1. There is no space before an opening quote.
2. There is an space before a closing quote.
3. There are nested or unwanted quotes within your input.

So it works regularly only on OP's such regular inputs.

Comment: Just FYI, `(?<=\b)` is the same as `(?=\b)` is the same as `\b`.

Comment: You made a good point, however, it's not needed at all. I removed it. @AlanMoore